# linux tutorial / book recommendation for php developers?

Tags: php, linux

We are working with a client who is using symfony/smarty and we are more used to using CI which do not require "installing" prior to it's usage.

I think we just need to advance a bit more into learning unix because "make" "make install" and even compiling apache is enough to rack our nerves because if it breaks, we can't fix it.  We can terminal in, do minor stuff (edit host files and virtual host files), but that's about it.

That being said, does anyone know of a good book or tutorial that dives into learning linux, but from the perspective of someone who may already be a decent programmer in PHP but used to interfacing with unix from FTP vs. the command line?  Maybe an "intermediate linux for web developers" book?  I've searched around for some, but there are so many books out there and it's hard to gauge which one would work at our level.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to spend a long time learning linux before you can successfully (and securely) set something up. You won't find a quick & dirty "Linux for PHP dummies".

That said, installing stuff is typically **extremely** easy. Don't compile stuff from source (using make/make install). Use `yum` or `apt-get` instead. Which one you can use depends on your linux distribution.

e.g.:

```
yum install httpd
```

This will do all the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

First off, let me say that this book will do what you are asking, bring you up to speed on *nix and pretty fast. It's called "Linux and the Unix Philosophy" by Mike Gancarz. You can read it pretty quickly, it's not that long. It's in my top 5 all time favorite *nix books.

If you know enough to get around on a system, then you are in better shape than you know. learning Apache is separate from learning *nix. I have several Apache books, but I honestly never use them. The Apache Foundation website has great documentation and there are a ton of forums out there to post just about any question. Apache is can be tough at first, but doable if you have the technical prowess.

So to your real question, a good book for learning Linux. 12 years ago I was handed a Red Hat Linux Unleashed book and within just a few days I knew enough to be dangerous and after a week, enough to actually make Linux work for me. Between Red Hat Linux Unleashed and another book called "Unix Power Tools" I was able to move from being a drafter to a Jr. Linux SysAdmin inside 3 months. The books + hands on is what worked for me. At a minimum, please check out "Linux and the Unix Philosophy".